# Creating an HTML form depending on database fields

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, fat-free-framework

I am trying to create a program that will read the structure of a database table and generate a simple HTML registration form depending on it. Like if the table looks like this:

```
TBLUSERS
- Name (varchar)
- Age (int)
- Birthday (date)
```

Then it would output a form like this:

```
<form id="generated-form">
   Name: <input type="text" id="name"><br>
   Age: <input type="text" id="age"><br>
   Birthday: <input type="date" id="birthday"><br>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But I don't know where to start. I prefer using anything that includes anything from Fatfree Framework since most of the project is done using it. Aside from this, I am only supposed to use HTML, JQuery, PHP and/or Javascript.

Any advices? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first step of course is to obtain the table's column information thru the use of [`DESCRIBE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/describe.html).

And then, you can just query it like any normal query, using `mysqli` in this case.

Example:

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$query = $db->query('DESCRIBE `TBLUSERS`');
$fields = array();
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $fields[] = $row['Field'];
}

?>

<form id="generate-form" type="POST">
    <?php foreach($fields as $field): ?>
        <label>
            <?php echo "$field: "; ?>
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo $field; ?>" />
        </label><br/>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Quick, simple, and just what I was looking for. Thank you so much, @ghost. :D

Comment: @Ghost its very help full but suppose I have select field i.e drop-down then how we can do that

Comment: @Sanj you'll need to specify an if condition inside the foreach, if text field, then use the above, if that field is a select, then do so, just create a simple select dropdown, just same concept, just a different html markup

Comment: @Ghost thanks for response +1 from my side to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Using Ghosts example including F3 and its template engine as requested

```
<?php

$f3 = require 'lib/base.php';

$db = new DB\SQL('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
$res = $db->exec('DESCRIBE `TBLUSERS`');

foreach($res as $row) {
    $fields[] = $row['Field'];
}

$f3->set('fields', $fields);

echo Template::instance()->render('form.html');

?>

<!-- form.html -->
<form id="generate-form" type="POST">
    <repeat group="{{@fields}}" value="{{@field}}">
        <label>
            {{@field}}:
            <input type="text" name="{{@field}}" />
        </label><br/>
    </repeat>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: It's really a big help that I make this happen in F3, but I am a novice F3 user and can't seem to make this work. It says "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()".

Comment: Either you're using my example wrong, or I made a mistake with the DB query and it doesn't return anything. Just try to `var_dump($res)` and see what's in it. I recommend you use @ikkez approach. I just forgot about schema()

Answer (score 1):

much easier in F3, and also multi-engine compatible:

```
$db = new DB\SQL('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
$schema = $db->schema('TBLUSERS');
$f3->set('fields', array_keys($schema));
```

also check for the full provided return value of schema: http://fatfreeframework.com/sql#schema

also posible in one line

```
$f3->set('fields', array_keys($db->schema('items')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
 <?php

$result = mysql_query ("SHOW COLUMNS FROM sometable" );
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result )) {
#$row contains a 3D-array of fields with their flags like
#Array
#(
#[Field] => name
#[Type] => varchar(7)
#[Null] =>
#[Key] => PRI
#[Default] =>
#[Extra] => auto_increment
#)

 #generate form like this
foreach($row as $column){
if($column[Type] == varchar(' /^[0-9]+$/i') $type= "text";
 elseif($other-types) $type = /*html-type-match*/;
 echo ucwords($column[Field])."<input type=\"$type\" />
}
?>
```

**This code is not tested**. Hope this is helpful to you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the form generation validations! Big help. :D

Comment: any time, user2176205.